# react app: issues running on internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, internet-explorer, npm

I have a react app. On Windows 10, it works fine on Chrome and Internet Explorer 11. But on Windows 7, it only works on Chrome, not internet explorer 11.

I get the below error:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'
```

through my research this looks like a compatibility issue with IE 11 (although not sure why it works on windows 10).

As far as I'm aware, something about polyfill/transfill(?)/babel needs to be used. But here is the bit I have the biggest issue with:

i have a bundle.js file that contains all the site code. this is a mixture of my own code, and NPM node modules. If the issue was with my code, then I'm fine with adding an import line and changing my code. but the error comes from the npm node modules. I can't edit these files. How can I resolve this Object.assign issue without touching those files?

I'm not really familiar with browser compatibility stuff so I'm quite stuck

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best long-term/community-friendly solution might be to identify which module is causing the problem and to file an issue with the maintainer(s) of the module. But if you need an immediate fix or if you can't figure out which module is causing the problem, you can try including an Object.assign polyfill before the offending module loads.

A polyfill is a piece of code that manually defines a feature (like Object.assign) for browsers that don't already support a given feature. In this case, you could include something like [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-object-assign), either by importing it into your bundle before the other modules, or by downloading and serving that polyfill file and loading it with a `<script>` tag in your HTML document before you load your bundle.js file. This way, Object.assign will be defined by the polyfill before your browser comes across the module code that calls Object.assign.

Comment: I think I need an immediate fix. What I have done regarding your link, is run npm install es6-object-assign, and in package.json i included the  "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0", in both dependencies and in devDependencies. In my index.html, in the body i reference my bundle, file. Above this I include the code:

Comment: <script src="node_modules/es6-object-assign/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script><script> var obj = Object.assign({}, { foo: 'bar' });</script>

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. I even restarted my npm webpack but i still get the same error. Is this how to use it?

Comment: this is my index.html body:
<body>
  <div id="app-root"></div>
  <script src="node_modules/es6-object-assign/dist/object-assign-auto.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
    var obj = Object.assign({}, { foo: 'bar' });
  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="dme-ui-bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
 </body>

Comment: managed to fix! i couldn't get it running on index.html, so i decided to add below code into one of the main parent js files. and it worked

Comment: import 'es6-object-assign/auto';
var obj = Object.assign({}, { foo: 'bar' });

Comment: If you are going to use the script tag, then you have to make sure that the server that is serving your index.html is also serving the polyfill script. Here you would have to be serving files from node_modules, but that probably isn't what you want. Instead, you can copy that script to the directory from which your index.html is served, or import the polyfill into your JavaScript file. Are you using babel or webpack or something else to generate your bundle.js? If so you should be able to write `require('es6-object-assign').polyfill()` at the top of your JavaScript file.

Comment: Oh perfect! Just saw your reply after I hit submit. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 2):

Another work around for peeps using 'create-react-app' and can't access the webpack config files, follow the following steps:

npm i babel-polyfill

and then :

// index.jsx
import 'babel-polyfill';

[Here is a good article over this approach.](https://www.mycodesmells.com/post/add-ie11-support-to-your-react-apps)